# How can I make manage screen behave like android singleTask mode?

Tags: react-native, navigation

Suppose the following screens:

> AScreen --> BScreen --> CScreen --> ASreen

Then use the `back` action go into home (identical on Android and IoS).

How can I make this behave like android's singleTask mode, when using:

> ("react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11" )

Answer (score 2):

You can use react navigation to achieve this.
Use `navigate` for navigation to screens A and B. Then on Screen C you can use [Backhandler](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler.html) to catch the back button press. Then reset the router which will pop the existing screens except the root (that is screen A).

The reset code would look like this:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile'}),
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Settings'})
  ]
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

Setting index to 0 will reset it to Profile. Setting it to 1 will reset to Settings Page. See the documentation on [navigation actions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions).